# How do i use the use the wooCommerce functions in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugins

How would i use the wooCommerce hooks in my wp plugin?
Here is what i am trying to do:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_edit_product_columns', 'pA_manage_posts_columns');
    function pA_manage_posts_columns($columns, $post_type = 'product') {
    global $woocommerce;
if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'product') ) ) {
        $columns['offering_price'] = __( 'offering price', 'your_text_domain' ); // this offering price title 
        $columns['offering_qty'] = __( 'Qty', 'your_text_domain' ); // add the quantity title
}
    unset($columns['name']);
return $columns;
```

}

I have included the woocommerce class:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$base_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)  . $ds . '..') . $ds;
$file = "{$base_dir}woocommerce{$ds}woocommerce.php"; 
include_once($file);
```

Comment: `add_filter('woocommerce_edit_product_columns', 'pA_manage_posts_columns',99);` try this

Comment: didn't work, i kinda think that woocommerce is not included in my plugin file, since i can't access the global $woocommerce either.

Comment: This isnt very difficult task to see if plugin is active .. is it ? please check it.

Comment: Thank you, I activated the plugin, include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
activate_plugin(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php'); still can't get the woocommerce hoook to add or remove the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, the hook is called differently

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', ... )
```

The 'woocommerce_edit_product_columns' is not a hook name, but a function name in WC 2.0

As for the access to global $woocommerce - as long as the WooCommerce plugin is loaded, it's available. If, however, your plugin is loaded before WooCommerce (alphabetically), then you can should do something within a function hooked to 'plugins_loaded'.